# Extract contents from p7m file with TurboPower LickBox

Tags: lockbox-3

I need to extract content from p7m files with Delphi 2010.
I wil try by TP Lockbox but I not find any instructions to how to do.

Comment: I wish obtain the result like of command line OpenSSL:"openssl smime -verify -in k:\SomeFile.XML.P7M -noverify -inform DER -out K:\SomeFile.XML"

Comment: Do you have a reference for a p7m standard or definition? If so, I can examine it.

Comment: No, I can not find the technical specifications anywhere.